# Reading columns in excel to c#

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am trying to read an excel file to c# but i want to convert column data to a string array and then to a string. I think i have done that here but am not sure. Anyways when i try to read the header of the excel column for my second if statement i get an error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array.". I am kind of a beginner and thus don't understand what i am doing wrong.

```
if (xlApp != null)
{
    //Doing excel things
    int i = SheetNum;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
    Excel.Sheets sheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(i);
    Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
    Excel.Range colRange = usedRange.Columns;
    Excel.Range firstRow = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows[1];

    int rowCount = colRange.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = colRange.Columns.Count;

    for (int m = 1; m < colCount; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n <= rowCount; n++)
        {
            System.Array myHeadvalues = (System.Array)firstRow.Cells.Value;
            string[] HeaderData = myHeadvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
            Excel.Range some = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[m];
            System.Array myNamevalues = (System.Array)some.Cells.Value;
            string[] result1 = myNamevalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();

            //String types
            if (result1.Contains("Name") && HeaderData.Contains("Name"))
            {
                string tagval = HeaderData[n].ToString() + ".Array" + 
                string[] result = result1.Skip(1).ToArray();
                string Inputs = result[n + 1].ToString();
                System.Console.WriteLine(tagval, Inputs);

            }

            //Error Appears here//
            else if (result1.Contains("Description") && HeaderData.Contains("Description"))
            {
                string tagval = HeaderData[n].ToString() + ".Array" + 
                string[] result = result1.Skip(1).ToArray();
                string Inputs = result[n].ToString();
                System.Console.WriteLine(tagval, Inputs);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `for (int n = 0; n <= rowCount; n++)` be `for (int n = 0; n < rowCount; n++)`?

Comment: Yea i tried that and i still get an error. The thing is that i was hoping not to read to the end of the rowCount because i have like 12 columns and like >500 lines.

Comment: You're writing `HeaderData[n]` which is trying to read the `nth` column of the headers (but `n` is iterating rows). You should change all occurrences of `HeaderData[n]` to be `HeaderData[m]`

Comment: Oh Okay that makes sense. I did what you suggested and still it comes up with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw i fixed my code now it reads across columns with no issue. If there is anyway i can speed it up please let me know. Thanks.

```
List<string> ColumnValues = new List<string>();
                for (int n = 2; n < rowCount; n++)
                {
                    for (int m = 1; m < colCount; m++)
                    {
                        Excel.Range some = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[m];

                        System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)some.Cells.Value;
                        string[] Data = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
                        ColumnValues = Data.ToList();
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues);
                        //String Types
                        if (ColumnValues.Contains("Name"))
                        {
                            string tagval = "Product_Array[0].Name";
                            string[] result = ColumnValues.Skip(1).ToArray();

                        }


                    }


                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is off-topic (I cannot comment yet), but it might be useful: it looks like you are using automation or something similar. I recommend using a library like [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (this is free), as it does need the Excel application to read and write Excel files. In most of the cases, the library will do the work faster than the Excel application.